# how to write a INNER JOIN on a subquery in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join, inner-join

I've a following `query` to select data from a table (*chat*) in a chat system:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id_chat = '$chat_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) S
WHERE id_chat = '$chat_id'
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

In this table (*chat*), there is a `user` column where it is the user id that sent the message.

I would, from the `id_from` of the user who sent the message, get back data that user (*users* table).

Table *chat*:

```
id | id_chat | id_from | id_to | message | date
1  | 23      | 1       | 2     | hello!  | 01-12-2016
```

Table *users*:

```
id | name | photo
1  | John | pic.png
2  | Nick | hey.jpg
```

What better way to do it using the above query? `LEFT JOIN`? `INNER JOIN`? And, how do?

Comment: the join type depends on whether you delete users on not. innerjoin would only get records where the associated user still exists, while left join would ignore missing users.

Comment: @MarcB So, I believe the `INNER JOIN` would solve my question, since there will always be the user in both tables, correct? If so, how I can adapt to query `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: up to you. you could do the join in either query. probably a bit more efficient to do it in the outer one, since there'd be no point in joining ALL of the chat message records, only to throw away all but the most recent 10.

Comment: @MarcB can you give me an example of how to do this `query`?

Comment: SELECT * FROM chat 
INNER JOIN users on chat.id_from = user.id
WHERE id_chat = $chat_id ORDER BY id DESC